# Module in use in CentOS/RHEL (lspci -k or lspci -v)

Tags: centos, redhat

How can I find which module is in use in CentOS 5.4 or 4.8?

For instance, in Fedora 12:

> lspci -k

```
(...)
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
 Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
 Kernel modules: iwl3945
```

In CentOS:

```
lspci -k

lspci: invalid option -- k
(...)
```

With lsmod:

> lsmod| grep (module)

I think i s not an option because I can't know which device is using the module.

Answer (score 1):

please update your **pciutils** package.

```
#yum install pciutils
```

and issue `lspci -k` it should work .

Answer (score 0):

http://linux.die.net/man/8/lspci

> -t
>
> Show a tree-like diagram containing
>   all buses, bridges, devices and
>   connections between them.

lspci -v as stated on your title should work aswell but it would list everything.

> -v
>
> Be verbose and display detailed
>   information about all devices.
>
> -vv
>
> Be very verbose and display more
>   details. This level includes
>   everything deemed useful.
>
> -vvv
>
> Be even more verbose and display
>   everything we are able to parse, even
>   if it doesn't look interesting at all
>   (e.g., undefined memory regions).

Answer (score 0):

you could also use lsmod

```
# lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
nfs                   231597  2
nfsd                  205489  17
exportfs                9665  1 nfsd
nfs_acl                 7617  2 nfs,nfsd
auth_rpcgss            43105  1 nfsd
autofs4                29253  3
coretemp               12609  0
w83627ehf              23241  0
hwmon_vid               6849  1 w83627ehf
hidp                   22977  2
l2cap                  29761  5 hidp
bluetooth              53797  2 hidp,l2cap
lockd                  63209  3 nfs,nfsd
sunrpc                149373  21 nfs,nfsd,nfs_acl,auth_rpcgss,lockd
cpufreq_ondemand       12493  1
acpi_cpufreq           13641  3
mperf                   6337  1 acpi_cpufreq
via_rhine              27597  0
be2iscsi               59221  0
ib_iser                35609  0
rdma_cm                35705  1 ib_iser
ib_cm                  39213  1 rdma_cm
iw_cm                  13125  1 rdma_cm
ib_sa                  39093  2 rdma_cm,ib_cm
ib_mad                 37717  2 ib_cm,ib_sa
ib_core                63557  6 ib_iser,rdma_cm,ib_cm,iw_cm,ib_sa,ib_mad
ib_addr                11717  1 rdma_cm
iscsi_tcp              20041  0
xfrm_nalgo             13381  0
crypto_api             12609  1 xfrm_nalgo
...
```